# Arduino-usbserial make is failing, error 1

Tags: gcc, makefile, arduino

http://flipmu.com/work/arduinome/instructions/uno-atmega-8u2-serial-number/

Trying to complete this using Windows, my intent is to flash the serial number from the atmega 8u2 in my Arduino Uno. I'm using Atmel Studio 6 as I'm on Windows.

I've downloaded the LUFA library as needed, followed the steps to the letter, and am getting this response from the command line:

```
e:\Downloads\LUFA-100807\Projects\arduino-usbserial>make build
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
ECHO is off.
Compiling C: Arduino-usbserial.c
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega8u2 -I. -gdwarf-2 -DF_CPU=16000000UL  -DF_CLOCK=16000000U
L  -DARDUINO_MODEL_PID=0x0001 -DBOARD=BOARD_USER  -D USB_DEVICE_ONLY -D FIXED_CO
NTROL_ENDPOINT_SIZE=8 -D FIXED_NUM_CONFIGURATIONS=1 -D USE_FLASH_DESCRIPTORS -D
INTERRUPT_CONTROL_ENDPOINT -D DEVICE_STATE_AS_GPIOR=0 -D USE_STATIC_OPTIONS="(US
B_DEVICE_OPT_FULLSPEED | USB_OPT_REG_ENABLED | USB_OPT_AUTO_PLL)" -DAVR_RESET_LI
NE_PORT="PORTD" -DAVR_RESET_LINE_DDR="DDRD" -DAVR_RESET_LINE_MASK="(1 << 7)" -DT
X_RX_LED_PULSE_MS=3 -DPING_PONG_LED_PULSE_MS=100 -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-
bitfields -ffunction-sections -fno-inline-small-functions -fpack-struct -fshort-
enums -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-adhlns=./Arduino-usbse
rial.lst -I../../ -std=gnu99 -Wundef -MMD -MP -MF .dep/Arduino-usbserial.o.d Ard
uino-usbserial.c -o Arduino-usbserial.o
In file included from ../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Device.h:60:0
,
                 from ../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/USBController
.h:73,
                 from ../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/USBTask.h:49,
                 from ../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/USB.h:370,
                 from Descriptors.h:42,
                 from Arduino-usbserial.h:45,
                 from Arduino-usbserial.c:37:
../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Endpoint.h: In function 'Endpoint_D
iscard_Byte':
../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Endpoint.h:572:13: warning: variabl
e 'Dummy' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Endpoint.h: In function 'Endpoint_D
iscard_Word':
../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Endpoint.h:656:13: warning: variabl
e 'Dummy' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Endpoint.h: In function 'Endpoint_D
iscard_DWord':
../../LUFA/Drivers/USB/HighLevel/../LowLevel/Endpoint.h:749:13: warning: variabl
e 'Dummy' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
Arduino-usbserial.c: At top level:
Arduino-usbserial.c:242:1: fatal error: opening dependency file .dep/Arduino-usb
serial.o.d: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Arduino-usbserial.o] Error 1
```

I've scoured through google for solutions to this problem and I haven't found anything - I've found similar 'Error 1' cases, but they were fixed by reverting to the version of LUFA I'm using. So I've got no clue.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Update:

Got the following response doing it this way instead:

http://autosysprogs.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/arduino-uno-upload-new-firmware-to.html

```
e:\uno\arduino-usbserial>make all
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
ECHO is off.
-------- begin --------
avr-gcc (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.4.0_663) 4.6.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
-f was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [sizebefore] Error 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not got an appropriate LUFA build environment set up - specifically, you are missing a Windows port of the Bash shell "sh.exe" that LUFA needs
 [see this](http://fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/120730/html/_page__compiling_apps.html#SSec_PreqWindows)

Comment: Thanks guys. Nailed it. Knew it was a rookie mistake!